# HTML/JS - SVG fill

Tags: svg

In my HTML code I have:

```
    <animate id= animationBottle attributeName="y1"
        from="101%"
        to="70%"
        begin="0s"
        dur="1s"
        fill="freeze"> 
    </animate>
```

Is there a way to make the 'to="70%"' variable with JS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sure, document.getElementById("animationBottle").setAttribute("to", "<whatever you want>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set the value (70%) of the attribute ("to") with Javascript.

```
document.getElementById("animationBottle").setAttribute("to", "70%");
```

If you have the value of 70 as a variable (`var value = 70`) and want to use that with the `setAttribute`, you do the following:

```
var value = 70;
var value_perc = `${value}%`;
document.getElementById("animationBottle").setAttribute("to", value_perc);
```

You could also make a function with the number as input.